# Images are being distorted on safari

Tags: html, css

On my site I am developing, I am having a problem with when I open the page in Safari all my images are being distorted. Chrome they work great.
Also not sure why when I resize on any browser, the images get squished.

Also, my intention was to make the images on the homepage links, however when i make them links, they are formatted so weird and don't work also.

Links to the sites are here:
Homepage with links: https://www.ryanstewsart.com/worklinks.html
How I want the homepage: https://www.ryanstewsart.com/work2.html
Project Page with only images (and some text): https://www.ryanstewsart.com/cassette2.html

HTML with the images as links:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 90vh;
}

img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="beansans.html"><img src="Images/Asset%2029.jpg" alt="Bean Sans" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>

  <a href="lentrata.html"><img src="Images/L2.jpg" alt="L'Entrata" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  <a href="ELEMENTS.html"><img src="Images/5.png" alt="alyx" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  <a href="nft.html"><img src="Images/opensea.png" alt="NFT Youngboy" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  <a href="alyx.html"><img src="Images/alyx1.jpg" alt="alyx" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  <a href="spoiler.html"><img src="Images/ThumbnailSpoiler.gif" alt="alyx" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  <a href="cassette.html"><img src="Images/cass-02%20copy.png" alt="Cassettes" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>

  <a href="lookat.html"><img src="Images/lookat-this2.gif" alt="Look at This Photograph" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>

  <a href="popper.html"><img src="Images/pillpopcovermock%202.jpg" alt="Pill Popper" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>

  <a href="canyon.html"><img src="Images/arenamock-Recoverevd.jpg" alt="Canyon Daze" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>

  <a href="mutiny.html"><img src="Images/ring-01.png" alt="Tendencies" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  <a href="tendencies.html"><img src="Images/22.jpg" alt="Tendencies" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
</div>
```

HTML when images are not links:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 90vh;
}

img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="Images/ThumbnailSpoiler.gif" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/alyx1.jpg" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/L2.jpg" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">


  <img src="Images/Asset%2029.jpg" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/TOBi/5.png" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/carti.png" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/WLR.png" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"><br>

  <img src="Images/LLA.png" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"><br>


  <img src="Images/lookat-this2.gif" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/pillpopcovermock%202.jpg" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/arenamock-Recoverevd.jpg" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/ring-01.png" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">

  <img src="Images/22.jpg" alt="spread" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise the snippets I added to demonstrate the problem (with placeholder images). Don't expect us to go out to other sites. Also, all that repeated styling should be in your CSS. `.container img {}` No one likes to work with such messy markup.

Comment: I would suggest that you create your layout grid using div elements (or similar) and put your content inside that. Using links and images as structural elements can be troublesome, especially if you decide later to modify the content. It's much easier if you have a separate layout grid.

Comment: You have set the height of the image but you've also set a maximum width so on some devices the image will have to be distorted to fit in.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that look by adding the same CSS you set for your `img` to the `a tag`.

```
a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px;
}
```